# Why is the Redux store being updated with a duplicate nested key?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I'm starting with React and Redux, so I've connected a component to Redux store, I got this component which is supposed to be a very simple login:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { findDOMNode } from "react-dom";
import RaisedButton from 'material-ui/lib/raised-button';
import TextField from 'material-ui/lib/text-field';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { loginRequest, loginSuccess, loginFailure } from '../actions';
import { browserHistory } from 'react-router';

class LoginForm extends Component {

  componentDidMount() {
    console.log(console.log(JSON.stringify(this.props,null,2)));
  }

  readyToSubmit() {

  }

  onSubmit(e) {
      e && e.preventDefault();
      let emailInput = findDOMNode(this.refs.emailInput).querySelector("input").value;
      let passwordInput = findDOMNode(this.refs.passwordInput).querySelector("input").value;
      if (emailInput.trim().length && passwordInput.trim().length) {
        if (emailInput.startsWith('hello')) {
          this.props.loginSuccess(emailInput);
        } else {
          console.log(emailInput);
          this.props.loginFailure(emailInput);
        }
      }
  }

  render() {
      let disabled = !!this.props.login.waiting || !!this.props.ready;
      return (
          <form onSubmit={::this.onSubmit}>
          <div>
            <TextField hint="E-mail" floatingLabelText="E-mail" ref="emailInput" onChange={::this.readyToSubmit}></TextField><br/>
          </div>
          <div>
            <TextField hint="Contraseña" floatingLabelText="Contraseña" type="password" ref="passwordInput" onChange={::this.readyToSubmit}></TextField><br/><br/>
          </div>
          <div>
            <RaisedButton type="submit" label="Acceder" primary={true} disabled={disabled} onClick={::this.onSubmit}/>
          </div>
        </form>
      );
  }
}

export default connect(
  state => {
    return {
      login: state.login
    }
  },
  {
    loginSuccess: loginSuccess,
    loginFailure: loginFailure,
    loginRequest: loginRequest
  })(LoginForm);
```

These are the actions:

```
export const loginSuccess = (email) => {
  return {type: 'LOGIN_SUCCESS', email: email };
}

export const loginFailure = (email) => {
  return {type: 'LOGIN_FAILURE', email: email };
}

export const loginRequest = (email) => {
  return {type: 'LOGIN_REQUEST', email: email};
}
```

These are my reducers:

```
const login = (state = {}, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'LOGIN_REQUEST':
      return {
        ...state.login,
        login: {
          waiting: true,
          email: action.email
        }
      };
      break;
    case 'LOGIN_SUCCESS':
      return {
          ...state.login,
          login: {
            waiting: false,
            email: action.email,
          },
          auth: {
            token: state.token
          }
      };
      break;
      case 'LOGIN_FAILURE':
        return {
            ...state.login,
            login: {
              waiting: false,
              email: action.email,
              errors: action.errors
            }
          };
        break;
    default:
      return {
        ...state.login,
        login: {
          ready: false
        }
      };
  }
}
export default login
```

So, the first strange stuff I notice is that `componentDidMount` logs:

```
{
  "login": {
    "login": {
      "ready": false
    }
  }
}
```

So I need some help on:

- **I can't figure out why is nested thay way (`login.login`)**.
- I'd like to get the button disabled only when both password and email fields are filled.
- I understand that Redux would *avoid* me of working with React's `state`, and that the connect function ties some store properties ot the component properties and some dispatchers to properties too .. but how can I easily access fields, button's etc values as part of the props.
- How can I ensure real deep merge at my reducers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it's likely going to be your reducers, instead of this:

```
case 'LOGIN_REQUEST':
    return {
        ...state.login,
        login: {
            waiting: true,
            email: action.email
        }
    };
break;
```

try this:

```
case 'LOGIN_REQUEST':
    return {
        ...state, <-- removed the .login from here
        login: {
            waiting: true,
            email: action.email
        }
    };
break;
```

or alternatively:

```
case 'LOGIN_REQUEST':
    return {
        ...state.login,
        //<-- removed the login key from the object you add to state.login
            waiting: true,
            email: action.email
    };
break;
```

Let us know if that helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Write the following:

```
state => {return state.login}
```

instead of

```
export default connect(
 state => {
   return {
   login: state.login
 }
```

Comment: This would probably work, but it doesn't solve the actual issues with the reducer.

Comment: If you give -1 please explain for the Op. I might have misunderstood the question

Comment: jolyonruss's answer explains the problem.

Comment: @JoeClay The issue is that "he can't figure out why it's nested", there's many different approach to that and I pointed out the easiest fix. The reducer is not necessarily the issue in itself - if you know what it returns

Comment: The reducer is the issue - they're updating the state wrong, and it's causing the key to get nested one level too deep (which isn't what they want, by the looks of things). Your code will make the component work, as you're mapping all the keys of `state.login` - in this case, just one, the accidentally nested `login` state - to the component, but it's just a band-aid over their actual problem.